# Regex. Pattern Match Perfmon Counter

Tags: regex, replace, backslash, perfmon

```
\\\\COMPUTER-NAME\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length
```

I am trying to parse the above string.

What I want to achieve is to strip out

```
\\\\COMPUTERNAME\\
```

and replace with "".

The regex pattern I thought would work is:

```
^\\\\\\\\.*\\\\
```

However using http://regexpal.com/, this seems to match

```
\\\\COMPUTER-NAME\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\
```

Can anyone help? Why is the regex pattern search just ignoring the first set of backslashes after the computer name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\\{4}.+?\\{2}`. That should do the job

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is greedy so it's matching everything it can, until it reaches the last backslash.

You can use `[^\\]*` to match everything *except* backslashes.